# CustomAdapter setText incorrect values

Tags: android, listview

The textView.setText sets all the items in the list as the same thing. How do I create a list of all the elements from my ArrayList? Do I need to specify the position somehow?

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

     private Context ctx;
     private ArrayList<String> children;

     CustomAdapter (ArrayList<String> data, Context context, String log) { 
         this.ctx = context;
         this.children = data;
     }

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){ 

          LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.text_list, null);

          TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.logText);
          System.out.println("Cyan");
          textView.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
          System.out.println("LOG SIZE: " + log.size());

          for(int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++){
              textView.setText(children.get(i));
          }
          return textView;
     }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return children.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    } 
 }
```

}

Comment: Small offtop, but never do this:
View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.text_list, null);
use 
View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.text_list, parent);

http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/?utm_source=%23AndroidDev+Weekly&utm_campaign=609fad7368-NEWSLETTER&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_f921dd69d1-609fad7368-61796877

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getView()` is called for each row passing in the position of the item it should use.  You are iterating through all of your children for each row which means that it's setting the `TextView` text multiple times and landing on the last child's text.  Your method should look more like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){ 

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.text_list, null);
    }

    TextView textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.logText);
    System.out.println("Cyan");
    textView.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
    System.out.println("LOG SIZE: " + log.size());
    textView.setText(children.get(position));

    return convertView;
}
```